# Working with Json API data and getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, dictionary

For my project, I have a file of student ID's that I have to match with the names, addresses, and phone numbers of students in the rest API. I wrote out this code but I keep getting the TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import requests
import csv
import re

outputfile = 'file.csv'
outfile = open(outputfile, mode='w', newline='')

master_key = ['name', 'address', 'phoneNumber']

writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, master_key, delimiter=",")
writer.writeheader()

with open('idfile.csv') as csv_file:
    open_file = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in open_file:
        for id in row:
            url = "https://schoolsite/studentIds/"
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.json()
            print(data)
            dict = {'name': data['input']['name'], 'address' : data['input']['address'], 'phoneNumber' : data['input']['phoneNumber']}
            writer.writerow(dict)
```

The data coming from the API looks like this:

> [{"input"{"name":"George Martin","address":"3452 Powelton
>   Ave","phoneNumber":"4563457368"}}]

I'm trying to create a csv with the student data organized by the header.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the resultant JSON data like it's a dictionary when you are receiving a list/array.

Assuming you only ever expect one data point in the list you can replace this line:

```
data = response.json()
```

with

```
data = response.json()[0]
```

and it'll work fine.

Comment: How would I change it if I am expecting multiple? What if each ID has a random number of data points?

Comment: That's up to you and how you want to handle it. I can't answer that for you.